# Using BehaviorSubject in Angular Services?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Reading through this article covering [OnPush Change Detection](https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/) and it features the following service that uses a `BehaviorSubject` to load a user:

```
    const ANONYMOUS_USER: User = {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: ''
    };


    @Injectable()
    export class UserService {

    private subject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(ANONYMOUS_USER);

    user$: Observable<User> = this.subject.asObservable();

    loadUser(user:User) {
        this.subject.next(user);
    }
  }
```

Suppose the `subject` reference is never updated with a new user.  In other words it sticks with the `ANONYMOUS_USER` state that it is initialized with.

Will all components that are injected with `UserService` and call loadUser receive an instance of the `ANONYMOUS_USER`.  IIUC that is the purpose of `BehaviorSubject`.  It remembers the current state so that `loadUser` can be called multiple times by different components and they will always receive the `ANONYMOUS_USER`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite.

All components that *subscribe* to `user$` will receive the ANONYMOUS_USER value from the subject.

So for example, if a component A subscribes, it will immediately get the ANONYMOUS_USER value. If the user navigates to another component B, the original component A is destroyed. If the user navigates back to component A and it resubscribes, it will get the ANONYMOUS_User value again.

This code:

```
loadUser(user:User) {
    this.subject.next(user);
}
```

Is what broadcasts a new value into the observable stream. So if any components call this method, they will broadcast a new value ... whatever they passed in to the method.

I have a complete example of using BehaviorSubject here: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-communication/tree/master/MH-Take3

And code that accomplishes the *same* task using getters/setters instead of BehaviorSubject here: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-communication/tree/master/MH-Take4

**EDIT:**

The main purpose of a Subject is to broadcast events to subscribers. It allows components to call a method (`loadUser` in this example) and pass a value. That value is then broadcast to all subscribers.

If you are using data binding, in most cases a subject is not needed. That is because Angular's change detection will provide the notification automatically.

A BehaviorSubject is a special type of Subject that has an initial value and provides that initial value to the subscriber when they subscribe. It is often used instead of a Subject if you need the subject to "remember" its last value.

Comment: What is main purpose of BehaviorSubject? Why I need know if data was updated?

Comment: I updated by answer to provide a bit more background information. Plus I have a video that walks through these techniques in detail here: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-component-communication. You can sign up for a free trial here: https://www.pluralsight.com/pricing